# Biblatex guide?

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)

It seems like biblatex is the way of the future for handling references in latex. The biblatex documentation file is a massive 288 pages, and not an easy read for beginners. Are there any walk-through or general guides out there on how to use biblatex? I have not found any.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex

Comment: Also, [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509) and (for customization) [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806)

Comment: I strongly disagree with the (currently two) votes to close this question: The previously posed questions on this subject are **not even close** to being substitutes to having a good answer (or, better yet, more than one good answer!) to the important question posed here: Is there a general purpose user guide for biblatex that qualifies as being user-friendly -- especially to those not yet familiar with biblatex? The existing reference manual wisely does *not* claim to be a user guide.

Comment: biblatex comes with a lot of usage examples, from easy to advanced, you can find them in your TeX tree or on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples)

Comment: @matth - yes, there are a lot of examples, but they are strewn about rather than being organized centrally, and they are not easy to find unless one has a lot of time to poke about in the reference manual. Moreover, if one's question doesn't happen to fall neatly into the format provided by the examples, there's very little a newbie can take away from studying the examples.

Comment: I think it might be useful here to define what is meant by a 'general guide'. As some of the comments mention, the basics of switching from 'standard' BibTeX to `biblatex` require only small source adjustments. On the other hand, creating a `biblatex` style is like creating a `.bst` file or a LaTeX package something that I would say is a task for 'programmers', not 'users' at all. (I get occasional messages for my `siunitx` package saying that the user guide is not sufficiently accessible, but this tends to come down to 'the quick start does not cover my particular use case'.)

Comment: @JosephWright - Actually, Torbjorn T. has already referenced that piece. :-) Given some of the significant changes implemented in version 2.0 of biblatex, it might be useful if you updated the answer you provided to that question.

Comment: @Mico Good point [both points :-)] Edit coming up to the other Q.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Are there any walk-through or general guides out there on how to use biblatex? I have not found any.

I'm afraid the reason for your lack of success in finding a walk-through or general guide to the `biblatex` package is rather simple: No such document appears to have been written so far. As you note, the package's [main documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) is very complete; however, it doesn't qualify as a user guide. To be sure, the document does not *claim* to be a user guide; it wisely notes that it is a "systematic reference manual".

That said, there *are* some online resources that are quite helpful to get beginners going on their way toward using the `biblatex` package competently. Some of these resources are contained in the questions (and associated answers) previously posted on TeX.SE and mentioned in the comments posted above. I heartily recommend that you study the information provided in those places. There are also quite a few biblatex experts who participate regularly in TeX.SE; questions posted on this site about biblatex specifics always appear to be answered quickly and in very helpful ways.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. `biblatex` doesn't need an extra introduction. The basics of bibliographies in combination with `bibtex` are the same. The differences are explained in the links in the comments above.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Why would one want to deny new users an introductory-level guide?

Comment: Agreed.  When people ask for this sort of guide, I think they're hoping for a walk-through of how to implement a style of some sort, and are daunted by the prospect of going from \DeclareBibliographyDriver to a full bibliography style.

Comment: Ironic question: `texdoc bibtex`. And every introduction of LaTeX has a section or chapter about bibliographies.

Comment: To be honest, everything is in the manual in easy to understand form, including examples. What might be nice is just an introduction of form "What section if I want to do X?" as the table of contents is rather high-level, expecially the "customisation" section which doesn't really tell you what's in there. I might look at this.

Comment: @Mico Would PLK's suggestion address the issues you see with the manual? As a user it never gave me much trouble. So it's hard to see how to improve. Any constructive feedback to this end would be [very welcome](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: @Audrey -- PLK's offer is definitely most welcome. :-) As the user guide project evolves, I'll be glad to offer constructive feedback. For that matter, I sincerely hope that the critiques I've offered up in this exchange will be interpreted as being constructive in nature as well. The `biblatex` package is great as it is; it just might well be even greater if it came with a user guide-level companion to the reference manual...

Comment: @Mico I've voted to close since the comments seem to suggest that an action will be taken later by PLK or Audrey. I also agree with you that something like a TikZ manual would be just fantastic.